# MVC not hitting controller action when dynamically built

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write out a pdf document to the users browser using a form post, now it works perfectly fine when i have it coded into my html like so:

```
<form method="post" action="~/Dashboard/CreateCertificate" target="_blank">
  <input value="1" name="id" style="display:none;">
  <input id="btnPDF" type="submit" value="View Certificate">
</form>
```

But when i dynamically create it and append it to my blank div, it gives me an error

```
if (this == false) {
  //Do something here
} else {
  tr = $('<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6"><div class="panel panel-info"><div class="Mypanel-heading"></div><div class="panel-body"></div><div class="panel-footer"><form method="post" action="~/Dashboard/CreateCertificate" target="_blank"><input value=" ' + 
    datain[i].Id + '" name="id" style="display:none;"><input id="btnPDF" type="submit" value="View Certificate"></form></div></div></div>');
  $('#courseTable').append(tr);
}
```

Bear in mind i hve taken out some of the div information that isnt relative to this issue

So my form is exactly the same as in my HTML, yet i get the following problem:

URL: localhost:56412/Home/Dashboard/~/Dashboard/CreateCertificate

The url when i dynamically build it up, does not go off to my controller

any help is appreciated

cheers

Comment: Remove the `~` in your `~/Dashboard/CreateCertificate`. It is now being appending using jQuery and Razor engine is no longer involved or able to translate it.

Comment: @haim770 I'm not sure that hard-wiring absolute paths is a sensible approach here. A relative path (e.g. one that doesn't start with a `/`) would be much safer in terms of porting the application to a different web-server.

Comment: @spender, I didn't mean that hard-writing the path is the way to go. Just pointed out the problem.

Comment: This isn't an iText question. The problem doesn't seem to be caused by iText (or iTextSharp), so why is it tagged as an iText question?

Comment: you're using MVC, so even using `~/Dashboard/CreateCertificate` is hard-wiring the path.. use `@Url.Action("CreateCertificate","Dashboard")` instead

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie, i have removed the itext tag.